# Redirect image URLs to new directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am migrating my site to a new software and need to redirect the old image URLs to new directory structures. This is the sort of pattern I need to redirect:

```
http://domain.com/galleries/directory1/*.gif > https://i.domain.com/galleries/1/big/*.gif 

http://domain.com/galleries/directory2/*.gif > https://i.domain.com/galleries/2/big/*.gif 

http://domain.com/galleries/directory3/*.gif > https://i.domain.com/galleries/3/big/*.gif 

http://domain.com/galleries/directory4/*.gif > https://i.domain.com/galleries/4/big/*.gif 

and so on


And also:
http://domain.com/upload/*year*/*month*/*day*/*.gif > https://i.domain.com/galleries/*year*/big/*.gif
```

Any help for what htaccess rules to use would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should do the trick.  However, be careful of collisions in file names from your uploads as the question doesn't specify different months and days in the target url.

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^upload/([0-9]*)/[0-9]*/[0-9]*/(.*.gif)$ "https://i.domain.com/galleries/$1/big/$2"    
 RedirectMatch "^/galleries/directory(.)/(.*\.gif)$" "https://i.domain.com/galleries/$1/big/$2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(galleries)/directory(\d+)/(.+?\.gif)$ http://i.%1/$1/$2/big/$3 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^upload/(\d+)/\d+/\d+/(.+?\.gif)$ http://i.%1/galleries/$1/big/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```